# See answer keys in Google Form (quiz) source page?

Tags: html, css, google-forms

Is there a way to the view the correct answers to this test quiz I made?
https://forms.gle/GgKVJrSTnDSLBEhF8

When I created the quiz I also set the keys to be shown once you complete all the form but the answers values in the source page are shown as "null". Is there a way to show them before completing the quiz?

```
</span></span></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" nonce="J/rILYt/GY+3CLlNicwpfQ">var FB_PUBLIC_LOAD_DATA_ = [null,["Is there a way to view the answers for this dynamic page? Answers for test1\u003db, test2\u003dj, Open answer text\u003dHello",[[1085708340,"Open answer: ",null,0,[[123642890,null,1]
]
]
,[193574675,"What is the first answer?",null,2,[[366340186,[["a",null,null,null,0]
,["b",null,null,null,0]
,["c",null,null,null,0]
,["d",null,null,null,0]
,["e",null,null,null,0]
]
,1,null,null,null,null,null,0]
]
]
,[987281703,"What is the second answer?",null,2,[[369282704,[["f",null,null,null,0]
,["g",null,null,null,0]
,["h",null,null,null,0]
,["i",null,null,null,0]
,["j",null,null,null,0]
]
,0,null,null,null,null,null,0]
]
]
]
,["Thank You!",1,0,0,0]
,null,null,[0,0]
,null,[1,""]
,"Test Quiz",48,[null,null,0,2,0]
,null,null,null,"it",[2]
,[[1,1,1,0,1]
,1,1]
,null,[]
]
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

no way. The only thing you could bypass is token and password. that thing could be visible through the html scipt itself by inspect it or view the source.

for the question, there is no way to show the correct answer. REMEMBER EXCEPT TOKEN AND PASSWORD.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot find answers by using inspect element. The reason is when you use inspect element you can see the code of the view of that page and in Google form quiz using inspect element will only show you the source of the questions in code of that page and not the answers as when you submit the form it only records your answers, your response and redirect you the response submitted page not the answers page. Its like a book where questions and in one page and answers on the other page which you cannot turn. However, inspect element can work on the sites or pages where the the answers are instantly revealed after submission because the response is present in the view code of same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use view source page, the only answers you will see is the text written ones that have a written answer that matches what your professor has written.